# Why is the DepartmentID value not being properly bound to the view model's property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Not sure why but the for some reason the view model is not binding the `DepartmentId` when I hit the submit button, I get an error:

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: value
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Not sure which value is being null as the code does not break, rather after hitting the submit button that is the message that is being displayed.

I'm assuming it's the `departmentId` that's not being properly bound to the DepartmentID property in CoursePreReqViewModel.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: value

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Catalog", "Courses", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pure-form pure-form-aligned" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input id="myInput" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, Model.DepartmentList, "Department", new { @class = "form-control required", id = "department-list" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Catalog(CoursePreReqViewModel viewModel)
{
    DepartmentRepo dRepo;
    CoursesRepo cRepo;
    MajorPreRequisitesRepo reqRepo;

    using (context)
    {
        dRepo = new DepartmentRepo(context);
        cRepo = new CoursesRepo(context);
        viewModel.PopulateDepermentSelectList(dRepo.GetAllDepartments());
        reqRepo = new MajorPreRequisitesRepo(context);
        viewModel.Courses = cRepo.GetAllCoursesAndPreReqsByDepartment(viewModel.DepartmentId);
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View model:

```
public class CoursePreReqViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public IList<MajorPreRequisite> CoursesAndPreReqs { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department: ")]
    public IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public CoursePreReqViewModel() { }

    public SelectList DepartmentList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(Departments, "Id", "Name");
        }
    }

    public void PopulateDepartmentSelectList(IList<Department> populatedDepartments)
    {
        Departments = populatedDepartments;
    }
}
```

Comment: What has led you to this assumption?  Which exact line of code throws the exception?  What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Because that is the only property that is supposed to bind to the CoursePreReqViewModel property, the program doesn't crash so there is no stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Exceptions have stack traces.  You should start by looking at this one’s.

Comment: Oh sorry, Here it is:
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value) +50408
   System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object container) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__1.MoveNext() +237
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +120
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sarthak here is another answer:  this is the asp.net mvc fiddler https://dotnetfiddle.net/ARdtvr
!!!Display Name needs to be a value!!!

Comment: Thanks, that did do the trick! Why does the attribute tag need a value for the model to properly bind? Adding that throws off my CSS and puts the search bar higher than the drop down list, that is why I initially removed that.

Comment: Without a name, an exception is thrown.  If I can find a better answer, I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you keep the code you have, and answer your question.

controller/classes:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
public class MajorPreRequisite
{
    public int MajorPreRequisiteId { get; set; }

}
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CoursePreReqViewModel
{
    //Make sure to comment this out -or- put this field in view
    //try this first with your code, before you change code eg using a dictionary
    //[Required]
    //[Display(Name = "")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public IList<MajorPreRequisite> CoursesAndPreReqs { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department: ")]
    public IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public CoursePreReqViewModel() { }
    public Dictionary<string, string> DepartmentList { get; set; }
    public void GetAllCoursesAndPreReqsByDepartment(IList<Course> populateCourses)
    {
        Courses = populateCourses;
    }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Catalog(CoursePreReqViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //Put a breakpoint herre to see departmentid of user choice
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Index11()
    {
        CoursePreReqViewModel viewModel = new CoursePreReqViewModel();
        Dictionary<string, string> depts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        depts.Add("1", "deptOne");
        depts.Add("2", "deptTwo");
        viewModel.DepartmentList = depts;

        IList<Course> courses = new List<Course>();
        courses.Add(new Course { CourseId = 1 });
        courses.Add(new Course { CourseId = 2 });
        viewModel.GetAllCoursesAndPreReqsByDepartment(courses);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

view:

```
@model WebApplication4what2.Controllers.CoursePreReqViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index11</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Catalog", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pure-form pure-form-aligned" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input id="myInput" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, new SelectList(Model.DepartmentList, "Key", "Value"), Model.DepartmentId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really sure what you did here, but I already have all these other models you've created, you can find them all here: https://github.com/SarthakThakur0097/BryantUniversity